# How do I get Linux on my sat nav?

Tags: windows, embedded

I have a Clarion MAP680 navigation system, with some version of Windows CE on it. Is there any way I could hack it to get my beloved Linux on it? 
It seems to have a 1 GB flash drive or something, and a SD card slot I've never used.

By the way, I have no hacking experience whatsoever.

Comment: This might be very difficult to do... do you know what CPU it uses?

Comment: @Renan It's a 400 MHz CPU, couldn't find out more.

Comment: [It's](http://gps.tech-details.com/Clarion_MAP680/) a [SiRFstarIII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SiRFstarIII). There's no board file in the mainline kernel, only one for the [prima2](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.10/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/sirf.txt), so the outlook isn't too good without doing a bit of programming yourself.

Comment: @Gilles What about BSD?

Comment: @MadTux I can't find anything in the NetBSD ports, so I guess you're out of luck.